# Unknown Error on Python. How to search for information from a list

Tags: list, python-3.x

Okay so I have a list with the layout like this:

['12345 3 G482 Emma Watson,

'12346 1 G485 Colean Green']

etc

Now the "3" and the "1" in both in this information are both Years.

So Emma Watson = year 3 and Colean Green = Year 1.

Now I want to have a function were the user will put in a range of years and it should print out the information that goes with the year.
For example. If user enters Years 3-1 the output will display

['12345 3 G482 Emma Watson,

'12346 1 G485 Colean Green']

but if the use enters something like 4-5 there will be no out.

I've trying something like this:  (Getting the information from a .txt file.

```
f = open(info)
    lines = f.readlines()
    ranges = [x for x in lines if list(range(1,3) in x.split()[1])]
    print(ranges)
```

However I get the error: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not range.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction please?

Comment: You are probably going to need the function `any`.

Comment: How will I use it in this case?

Comment: lol I searched SO for "Emma Watson" just on a whim and I actually got several results, this being the first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ranges = [x for x in lines if list(range(1,3) in x.split()[1])]
```

`range(1,3) in x.split()[1]` doesn't really make sense because you're effectively asking if the value `[1,2]` is inside the string. Lists can't exist inside a string, so it raises an error.

Try using `any` to test to see if any of the numbers in the range are inside the string.

```
ranges = [x for x in lines if any(str(num) == x.split()[1] for num in range(1,3))]
```